# Multiple Function Declaration Flagging Compiler Error VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have function declarations which have been updated to accommodate both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows (VBA6 & VBA7).  I would like to keep both declarations, since some of our clients still use Excel 2007.

The problem is that the VBA6 declarations (following the Else statement) seem to sometimes (though not always) throw a compiler error in Excel 2016 (tested on Office 365, 64 bit) upon opening the application, *even though it will never be read*.

(Compile error:  The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems.  Please review and update Declare statements and mark them with the PtrSafe attribute.)

Is there any way that this can be avoided?

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long


Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal 
dwProcessId As Long) As Long

#Else
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: `have been updated to accommodate both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows` - they have not been. They have been tagged with the `PtrSafe` keyword, but the parameter types remained wrong (`Long`). They will crash on x64.

Comment: Regarding the actual error, I doubt it's the functions in the `#else` block. You probably missed a function when you went to tag everything `PtrSafe`.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of the PtrSafe Function `WaitForSingleObject` is wrong. Here is the corret version.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
                  Alias "WaitForSingleObject" ( _
                        ByVal hHandle As LongPtr, _
                        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long _
                        ) As Long
```

Comment: Declaration of `OpenProcess` is also wrong, but VBA does not know about either. It would not cause the OP's error.

Comment: @SGerg Yes indeed. I overlooked that. The return value of `OpenProcess` is of LongPtr type for the VB7 version. My approach to the error message is to eliminate known errors first and hope that no errors remain. VBA's error messages don't always reflect the true cause of errors.

Comment: Updated the code to read:   `Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hHandle As LongPtr, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long


Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr`      Still the same error.  FYI, all of the lines in the Else clause are in red font, as if they are in error and the software has been working with the code as it was.  I just want to get rid of the error.

Comment: @SGerg seems to have been smarter than I. Apparently he foresaw the trouble brewing. :-) Try the WIN64 constant in place of VBA 7. Read up on the subject here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx